# Should I use a single function or an object in OOP?

Tags: php, function, oop, object

I'm new to OOP, and I want to know if I should use a single function, or an object.
Should I do this:

```
class Escape_String{
    protected $string;

    function __construct($string){
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc)
            return $string;
        else
            return addslashes($string);
    }
}

$string = new Escape_String($_GET['string']);
```

or should I just use a function instead of an object? (Like this:)

```
escapeString($string){
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc)
        return $string;
    else
        return addslashes($string);
}

$string = escapeString($_GET['string']);
```

of course the real object Escape_String/function escapeString are a little bit more complicated, but you should know what I mean

Comment: Would the `Escape_String` object do anything else other than just `addslashes`?  Because if not, a class seems like overkill.

Comment: Neither. What you want to do is the wrong approach. Use [PDO prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Solved:

I'll make a class called "Escape" or similar, then I'll put multiple static functions in it for different "types" (MySQL queries, Strings, arrays etc.)

Comment: I'm surprised that no one has pointed out that constructors cannot return anything (other than an instance of the class they belong to, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in you case it is better to name class something like StringUtils and to make static method escapeString

I recommend to read a book like http://shop.oreilly.com/product/mobile/9780596007126.do and reading sourse code of popular frameworks like Symfony2

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
class StringUtil
{

    static public function escapeString( $string )
    {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc) {
            return $string;
        } else {
            return addslashes($string);
        }
    }

}
```

It is static for easy use.

```
echo StringUtil::escapeString($string);
```

Comment: You should add a little explanation of why you used a static method for future users. +1

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would say this is best suited as a function or as a public static method on a class, if you have other similar methods you want to group into a class library.  I would not make a class just for this method however.